# English idiom related to time

Tags: idioms, proverbs

I wonder what is the English idiom with the following meaning.

"There are two opinions and only time could decide what is true".

It should be something like "survive time's exam" or something like that.

Comment: The idiom is ***survive the test of time***.

Comment: Also, "time will tell."

Comment: "Resistance is futile, you will be assimilated and your opinion will decimated."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not sure I agree about '*Stand the test of time*'. It is used in a different sense to the one the OP is seeking. If you are, for example, unsure whether a particular product will sell in the long run, or just be a passing fad, one would ask '*Will it stand the test of time?*'.

But the OP is looking for a term which indicates that time will supply the answer as to which of two opinions is correct. For example - will a vaccine for Covid-19 prove possible? In that case '*time will tell*', would seem more appropriate.

Comment: I agree, the best usage would be "...and only time will tell which, if any, are correct".

Comment: You could say, though, that only one of the two opinions will stand the test of time.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, yes, that could be done, but requires many more words to clarify that only one of multiple things (opinions) will be left still standing after some time. _Time will tell_ is short and sweet.

Answer (score 3):

***[To stand the test of time](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stand_the_test_of_time)*** is a reasonably fixed idiom that conveys exactly what you're trying to describe:

> To remain useful or valued over a long period of time; to last a long time.

Comment: This is incorrect. "Stand[ing] the test of time" applies when talking about the durability and resiliance of something. As noted by WS2 the OP is asserting that the truth of a matter will become known only after the passing of time. Not the same thing.

Comment: _To stand the test of time_ doesn't really apply here. What is wanted is something that "the passage of time will prove which (of two or more) alternatives is correct", rather than "some thing has shown that it is durable". _Time will tell_ comes much closer.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [In the fullness of time](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/in-the-fullness-of-time) may also be used in the context:

> After a due amount of time have elapsed.

In the fulness of time we will know which is true.

Comment: That's an idiom?  I've never heard that before.

Comment: I guess it is, I provided a link plus it can be easily found in general reference.

Comment: @KristinaLopez In my view it is a greatly overworked idiom, used in all kinds of different and vague contexts.

Comment: I've never heard it here in the US Midwest.  It proves you can learn something new every day! :-)

Comment: Yes, I think that one of the positive aspects  of this site is that it is truly international!! We all learn something new everyday.

Answer (score 2):

A fairly commonly used idiom where I live is [*only time will tell*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/time+will+tell). It is used to convey the exact meaning you state above.

Answer (score 1):

Another popular English phrase is *que sera sera*, which according to [oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/que-sera-sera) is “Used to convey a fatalistic recognition that future events are out of the speaker’s control”, and what may be, only time will tell.  This English phrase is, according to [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/qu%C3%A9_ser%C3%A1,_ser%C3%A1), from the Italian “che sarà, sarà” via grammatically-incorrect Spanish *qué será, será*: “The correct form would be lo que será, será”.